# node.js Socket.io cors from null

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I created a server over ssl with Node.js and I will use socket.io.
When I type https://socket.com/test on the browser via my code below, it works. There is no problem.

```
var express = require('express');
var https = require('https');
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');
var io = require('socket.io')(https);
// This line is from the Node.js HTTPS documentation.
var options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ssl-keys/crunchsystem/key.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/ssl/ssl-keys/crunchsystem/cert.pem')
};

var app = express();
// Create a service (the app object is just a callback).
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.get('/test',function(request, response) {
response.send(JSON.stringify({ status:'ok' }));
 });


app.post('/order', function(request, response) {
if (request.body.restaurant_code !== undefined) {
io.of('/'+request.body.restaurant_code).emit('GetOrder', request.body.data);
}
response.send(JSON.stringify({ status: request.body.restaurant_code }));
 });


// Create an HTTP service.
http.createServer(app).listen(80);
// Create an HTTPS service identical to the HTTP service.
https.createServer(options, app).listen(443);
```

However ... When I try to listen to the channel, it keeps giving a cors error.

```
<script type="text/javascript" 
src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/2.0.4/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io.connect('https://socket.crunchsystems.com/foo');
    console.log(socket);
socket.on('GetOrder', msg => {
    console.log(msg)
  })
</script>


from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

There's always this error.How do I solve this error? Can you help me?
I've tried all kinds of solutions, I've tried everything that happens on the Internet.

Comment: Have you tried allowing cors on yuur server side code using expressjs ??

Comment: you could install a package called cors and use it like const cors = require('cors');
app.use(cors()); This might solve.

Comment: ı tried it...yes

Comment: has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.